# error while calling a soap webservice in eclipse

Tags: java

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://***/fiwebservice/services/FIUsbWebService
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1459)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
    at com.abcde.testClient.TestClientTry.main(TestClientTry.java:109)
```

I have replaced the url as *** for security purpose, as it is confidential..

Why is there an error when I call a soap webservice in eclipse?

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Look into your server logfiles. 500 is a `internal server error`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an error in com.abcde.testClient.TestClientTry. Could you provide the logs and the the source of the File?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status code 500 usually means that the web server code crashes. 
If `HttpURLConnection#getResponseCode()` and error and `HttpURLConnectionof#getErrorStream()` instead of (to the status code to determine in advance), it is necessary to read. It can in other words, information about the problem.

Host if blocked you, you have got the code 4NN State, as the more 401 and 403rd

Comment: <soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode><faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The processing instruction target matching &quot;[xX][mM][lL]&quot; is not allowed. Message being parsed: </faultstring></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
WebService outputString:


java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://*****/fiwebservice/services/FIUsbWebService

Answer (score 0):

Http 500 can mean many things. In Spring security I think that can mean that you didnt have the appropriate authentication to reach the resource. Without knowing much about your server side its hard to say what the problem is or how to solve it.

What kind of technology did you have at the server?